# No results from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, class, oop

I'm trying to make a page to show branches which are taken from a database table, but I got "0 result" without any error.
I am not sure what I am doing wrong in my code, I feel there is a missing variable or something. I hope you can help me.
Please find my code files below :

index.php:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ar" dir="rtl">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Nectar Branches</title>
      </head>
      <body>
            <form action="view.php" method="post">
              <label for="city">Choose a city:</label>
              <select name="city">
                <option value="makkah">makkah</option>
                <option value="jeddah">jeddah</option>
                <option value="medina">medina</option>
              </select>
              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="search">
          </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

view.php:

```
<?php 
    require_once 'classes/Branch.php';

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

      $br = new Branch;
      $br->getBranch();

    }

    ?>
```

Branch.php :

```
<?php

        require_once 'Database.php';

        class Branch extends Database {

          public function getBranch() {

              $city = $_POST['city'];

              $sql = "SELECT * FROM branches WHERE brCity = ?";
              $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
              $stmt->bind_param("s", $city);
              $stmt->execute();
              $result = $stmt->get_result();

              if(!empty($result) && $result->num_rows > 0) {
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["brName"]. " " . $row["brCity"]. "<br>";
                            }
                        } else {
                            echo "0 results";
                        }

              }
          }

    ?>
```

Database.php :

```
<?php
  class Database {
    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $pwd;
    private $dbName;
    public $conn;


    public function connect() {
      $this->host = "localhost";
      $this->user = "root";
      $this->pwd = "";
      $this->dbName = "branchs";
      //create connection
      $conn = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pwd, $this->dbName);

      return $conn;

    }

  }

?>
```

Comment: Are your `option` values in the `select` element absolutely equal to the entries in the database?

Comment: You need to be checking results for all your actions. DB initialization, statement preparation, parameter binding, execution, you do it all without checking to see if anything actually works.

Comment: @El_Vanja Yes it's equal.

Comment: @miken32 What's the best way to make checking ?

Comment: To check, read the documentation of the functions you're using. See what each of them returns on failure and check your variables against that.

Comment: @El_Vanja I've checked right now and I got Execute failed: (2006) MySQL server has gone away